# Position sticky thats not taking up space

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to make a sidebar that acts as fixed **but is limited to a certain div**. As you may know, `position: sticky` attribute in css switches between `position: relative` and `postition: fixed`. The problem with this(as far as I know), is that `position: relative` cannot be used to make the element float over other elements so it leaves an empty space in the website.

My code:

HTML:

```
<!--Top text-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>


<div class="container">
<!--Sidebar-->
     <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close" id="closefilter"></a>
       <div id="filterheader">Filter</div>
       <div id="filtercontent">
         <div id="subfilterheader">Platforms</div>
         <ul style="list-style: none;" id="filterlist">
           <li>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input id="filtersteam" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('steam')" />Steam</label>
             </div>
           </li>
           <li>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input id="filterepic" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('epic')" />Epic</label>
             </div>
           </li>
           <li>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input id="filterorigin" type="checkbox" rel="origin" onchange="changeFilter('origin')" />Origin</label>
             </div>
           </li>
           <li>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input id="filtergog" type="checkbox" rel="gog" onchange="changeFilter('gog')" />GOG</label>
             </div>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
     <!--Middle text-->
     <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
     <div class="main-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
     </div>
   </div>

<!--Bottom text-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
}


.sidenav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 250px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }


  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .sidenav #filterheader {
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
  }


  #subfilterheader{
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  #filterlist{
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
  }


  .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  .close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .close:before, .close:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    content: ' ';
    height: 33px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .close:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .close:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
```

JS: (opening and closing of the sidebar)

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru2q7ydj/

 As you can see here, the sidebar is working as it should - it is fixed and limited to the div `container` at the same time. There is however an empty space in the page because of the `relative` property of the sidebar. If we change the sticky atribute to absolute - https://jsfiddle.net/ru2q7ydj/1/ the space goes away (but of course the sticky functionality as well)
**Is there a way to get rid of that space while keeping these functionalities?**

Comment: You could try to use `display: grid` on the `div.container` element. Of course you will need to move the open "button" inside `div.main-content` element

Comment: That doesn't really do it: https://jsfiddle.net/ru2q7ydj/2/ but thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: because with `display: grid` you need as well `grid-template-columns` property see the snippet in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution where I've added `display: grid` on the container and moved the open button inside div.main-content.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  
  /* new lines */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 1fr;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav #filterheader {
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}


#subfilterheader {
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#filterlist {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Top text-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>


<div class="container">
  <!--Sidebar-->
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close" id="closefilter"></a>
    <div id="filterheader">Filter</div>
    <div id="filtercontent">
      <div id="subfilterheader">Platforms</div>
      <ul style="list-style: none;" id="filterlist">
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtersteam" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('steam')" />Steam</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterepic" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('epic')" />Epic</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterorigin" type="checkbox" rel="origin" onchange="changeFilter('origin')" />Origin</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtergog" type="checkbox" rel="gog" onchange="changeFilter('gog')" />GOG</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Middle text-->
  <!-- <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span> -->
  <div class="main-content">

    <!-- new line --> <p>
      <!-- new line --> <span style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
      <!-- new line --> </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetdipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetdipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis egetLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Bottom text-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
and I solved it with using `position:fixed`
which is position absolute + sticky
this way it doesn't take space in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you add container to it with `position: absolute` it works

```css
.abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 250px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<div class='abs'>

     <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5d7xs2h3/

Comment: If I do that, the sidebar won't be limited to the div.

Comment: I added another answer that may help you

Comment: In the other answer the sidebar unfortunately isn't sticky.

Comment: can you take a look again?